# Reading from a file and counting the words in the file

Tags: c#, regex, grammar

I'm running through a list of project ideas, my goal is to do them all and hopefully by then I'll be pretty decent at `c#`. I have written a program that will count the amount of words in a given file, it works however there's a bug in it.

How it works:

- The file name is given as a prompt, the user inputs the file path or name.
- The file is then run through a regex: `"[a-zA-Z]+"` that splits the words into an array.
- The length of the array is then counted.

The only trouble I'm having is if you use a `'` (apostrophe) it will split the word into two words, for example if I read from a file that says: `this is a test of my program and now I'm going to test it again, to see what happens...` it will output `20` when it should output `19` because it splits `I'm` into two words. Is there a way I can get the regex to compensate for proper grammar use, or is there a way I can do this without a `regex`?

Source:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Reg = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex;

namespace count
{
    class CountWordsInString
    {
        static string Count(string list)
        {
            string[] arrStr = Reg.Split(list, "[a-zA-Z]+");
            int length = arrStr.Length - 1;

            return length.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter file path: ");
            var file = Console.ReadLine();

            var info = File.ReadAllText(file);

            Console.WriteLine(Count(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/dK4gS7/1)**..just match it..don't split it..

Comment: considering word only contains alphabets and not numerics

Comment: @rock321987 I thought about that, but this was easier, because I knew how to use the regex

Comment: `match` is also part of regex

Comment: @rock321987 I didn't think about using `match` valid point, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my opinion, if you want to count words you do not need RegEx. RegEx is a big library and can consume a lot of resources if you do not take care of how to use it.

the split function is a better choice, load the text on a variable and apply the split method in this way:

`string[] separators = {" ","\r\n", "\n"};
string value = "the string that will be word counted";
string[] words = value.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(words.Count);`

Comment: I think this solution is better suited, even more if you add a few chars that could separate words without space : "/", "\", ";" (csv data), "|". Also if you have to count numbers, you have to think about operators.

Answer (score 2):

A way you could do this would be to match anything that isn't whitespace (spaces tabs etc.). This can be accomplished with a negated character class like this:

```
[^\s]+
```

The `^` denotes a character class that will match anything except for the characters in it. This assumes of course that your definition of "word" is a string split up on spaces.

Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/sM1oJ3/1).

Comment: I like how you had it say `Hello I can't help not matching on apostrophes.` lol. Thanks for this, good answer.

Comment: good one! just a note, since this is c#, you will need to escape the \ like this `[^\\s]+`

Answer (score 1):

If you want "words" to contain optional apostrophes, you could use the regex

```
[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)*
```

That will match words which contain apostrophes, as long as the apostrophe is surrounded by letters. So it will match `fo'c's'le` (a word, according to the Ubuntu dictionary), but not `a''b` or `'Twas`. For word-counting, initial and final apostrophes don't make any difference -- `'Twas` is counted as one word either way -- but if you want to do something with the word, like spell-check it, then you'll need a more sophisticated approach to correctly handle `'Twas` while still extracting the word `Go` from:

```
"Start running when I say 'Go!'," he said.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; //regex
using System.IO; //File reading

#region //Return the count of words in a file
public int wordamount(string filename) 
{
     return Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(filename), @"\w+|\w+\'\w+").Count; //Match all the alphanumeric characters, and or with commas
}
#endregion
```